# Q_PROPERTY and has no member error

Tags: qt, qt4

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to create some properties in a class (as I did before) but this time I'm getting the error *"class Foo has no member named MyProp"*

The header is:

```
#ifndef P_H
#define P_H

#include <QObject>

class P : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int Prop READ getProp WRITE setProp)
  public:
    explicit P(QObject *parent = 0);

    int getProp() const;
    void setProp(int nP);
  private:
    int m_p;
};

#endif // P_H
```

and the cpp file is:

```
#include "p.h"

P::P(QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent)
{
}

int P::getProp() const
{
  return m_p;
}

void P::setProp(int nP)
{
  m_p = nP;
}
```

But when I try to use foobar.P I got the error *class P has no member named P*. I've been reading [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html) and I can't see any difference. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Qt Creator 2.4.1 and Qt 4.8.

[... Edit ...]

Here is how I'm trying to use it:

```
#include "p.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  P c;

  c.Prop = 2;

  return 0;
}
```

This is the simplest example I could think of and I got the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you use it ?
A property can be read and written using the generic functions QObject::property() and QObject::setProperty()

Comment: I'm trying to use it as it was a public member. If I have to use those Object methods I think I'll prefer to use the accesor methods I already have.

Comment: Can you show the actual code how you access it? Since getProp() and setProp() are not more than normal class members from C++ perspective, you can also call them directly like foobar.getProp() and foobar.setProp(42). The error message indicates that you are trying something else.

Comment: I know I can access using those methods, but if I hav to use them I wouldn't need the property. I would like to use the property because is shorter O:-), and I think it's more clear.

Comment: The weird thing is that I'm pretty sure I did this before the same way and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it like this:

```
P c;
c.setProperty("Prop", 42);  // set the property
c.property("Prop");         // retrieve the property
```